# How can I add meta description and title to my MVC3 pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me if there is a recommended way to add Meta information to MVC3 pages. The kind of information that I would like to add is title, description, keywords.

Thanks,

Gemma

Answer (score 6):

I'd use `ViewBag` for the title and `RenderSection` for the rest of the head content.  This goes in the Master Layout file (_Layout.cshtml):

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("head", false);
</head>
```

In your individual views, you will add:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page Title";
}

@section head {
    <meta name="description" content="best site ever">
}
```

EDIT:

Note that the `@section head {...}` block is optional.  You will not get a compilation error if you omit this block.  On views where you want metadata you'd supply it.

Comment: this will mean you will have to specify the meta on every page - not exactly DRY?

Comment: If you wanted every view in your site to serve identical metadata, I'd consider an alternative.  RenderSection allows flexibility for individual views to support tailored metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add it as a seperate view - that way you can call:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Head", "Header");}
```

from within your various layouts and have the same correct header data rendered.

hth

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in master page, we put a `ContentPlaceHolder` control, call it `TitleContent` like this:

```
<head>
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
</head>
```

And in children pages:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Some Title
</asp:Content>
```

The same thing can be done for Meta Tags, or you could make a full ContentPlaceHolder for `HeadContent` and fill it with (title/meta...) in each page individually.

Comment: question is about MVC application, not WebForms app

Comment: Yes, MVC. I have a full-fledged MVC project and use the syntax above within it. and the OP didn't specify he is using Razor.

Comment: @alexanderb asp.net WebForms View engine can be simply used in mvc, and the answer is good if Gemma uses web forms view engine. I don't understand what are you complaining about

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I'm using Razor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put metatags inside the HEAD tag of HTML. For MVC application it depends there you have HEAD. It could be either page (*.cshmtl) of layout (Layout.cshtml). It is quite better to place into layout, since meta info is shared throught the rest of pages.

```
// *.cshtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <meta ... />
</html>
</head>
```